# DV360 API. Create target for lien item

Tags: google-api, dv360

I'm trying to create an ageRange target for a line item using the DV360 API. However, I require targetOptionId. Where can I get it?

(https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v1/advertisers.lineItems.targetingTypes.assignedTargetingOptions/create?apix_params=%7B%22advertiserId%22% 3A613810781% 2C% 22lineItemId% 22% 3A15014994889% 2C% 22targetingType% 22% 3A% 22TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE% 22% 2C% 22resource% 22% 3A% 7B% 22ageRangeDetails24% 22% 3Aagne% 22GE_RANAGE% 22% 3Aagne% 22GE_RANAGE% 22 7D% 7D% 7D)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ignat - you need to first get the ids for different targeting options using another api - https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v1/targetingTypes.targetingOptions/list and then you need to pass that targetOptionId in your request.